# How to auto paste above return value on command line

Tags: command-line, script, mac-address

I am trying to create a very simple script (.command) that 
will basically change my mac address.. i do know that the command: `openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//'` will return me a random hex digits, now I want that when it will run this line `sudo ifconfig en0 ether ##` the hash tag will replace the random hex digits that it returned above.

thank you,
mendel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't exactly the most elegant way to do this but the following will work:

```
MAC="$( openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' )" && sudo ifconfig en0 ether $MAC
```

The above is how you could do that in a single command. It makes use of bash's [variables](https://ryanstutorials.net/bash-scripting-tutorial/bash-variables.php). The first part assigns the vairable `MAC` to the output of your randomisation command then the second part inserts this output where you desire by referencing `$MAC`. If you're looking to integrate it into a bash script, you can modify it slightly like below; which does exactly the same thing just on multiple lines:

```
#! /bin/bash

MAC="$( openssl rand -hex 6 | sed 's/\(..\)/\1:/g; s/.$//' )" 

sudo ifconfig en0 ether $MAC
```

Hope that helps!

Kind regards, Tom

Comment: thank you very much, i was thinking of some variable method to solve it but im kidda new to the command line ;/

Comment: @Mendel No worries, glad I could help!